# Center 3 Column Grid Inside 100% Width Div

Tags: css, layout, grid

I have a 3 column grid, which is sitting inside a 100% container div. But as of now it is just being pulled all the way to the left side of the page. I want the three columns to be div to be centered inside the container. Here is a screenshot of the design that I'm trying to code: [image] To fix the margin issue between each grid box, I used the technique [found here](http://csswizardry.com/2011/08/building-better-grid-systems/) (Scroll down to the last section "Roll your own...")

HTML:

```
<div class="featured-properties">
    <div class="properties">
        <div class="property">
            <img src="img/sample-prop-1.jpg" alt="Sample Property" />
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            <img src="img/sample-prop-2.jpg" alt="Sample Property" />
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            <img src="img/sample-prop-3.jpg" alt="Sample Property" />
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            <img src="img/sample-prop-4.jpg" alt="Sample Property" />
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            <img src="img/sample-prop-5.jpg" alt="Sample Property" />
        </div>

        <div class="property">
            <img src="img/sample-prop-6.jpg" alt="Sample Property" />
        </div>
    </div><!-- end .properties -->
</div><!-- end .featured-properties -->
```

CSS:

```
.featured-properties {
  width: 100%;
}


  .properties {
    margin: -79px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    width: 1047px;
  }

    .property {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 79px;
    }
```

Comment: Where are the three columns you want to define? All you have are 6 individual images in their own containers all inside an outer container packaged inside yet another outer container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need explanation, see the CSS below and demo (responsive!).

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/0m5p2818/

```
.properties {
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 720px; /* (200+(20x2))x3 */
    font-size: 0; /* fix for white space bug */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.property {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure if I understood your question, but I think CSS 3 Flexbox can help you to achieve what I think you need.

Take a look at it here and see if it works for you: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Browser support is terrible

Comment: Well, acording to: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex, If you are not targeting IE 9 it should be fine. Sorry it didn't help though